# How to use Contacts (partnet) address fields in custom model in Odoo

Tags: odoo

In the contact application we can see that every contact (partner model) has an address. That address if form by several fields (Street, Street 2, city, state, zip, country) How can a add those fields to a custom model. I net the code for both the model and the view

This is what I want for my custom model

[image]

Comment: I very ***very*** much hope that is dummy data and not actual customer data.

Comment: What I ment is that a want to use that address fields in a cstom model

Comment: create your custom model for using `address field` inherit that model from `res.partner`

Answer (score 0):

new_model_name/models/res_partner.py

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class ResPartner(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'res.partner'

 new_field = fields.Char(string='Full Address', compute='_compute_full_address', store=True)

 @api.depends('street', 'street2', 'city', 'state_id', 'country_id')
 def _compute_full_address(self)
  for r in self:
   r.new_field = f'{r.street}, {r.street2}, {r.city}, {r.state_id.name}, {r.country_id.name}'
```

new_model_name/views/res_partner_views.xml

```
<odoo>
 <record id="res_partner_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">res.partner.view.form</field>
  <field name="model">res.partner</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
   <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_address_format')]" position="inside">
    <field name="new_field" />
   </xpath>
  </field>
 </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: That won't be a new model, which the question was about.

Comment: then you can create a new model, set a partner_id to get what related